android java error on replying to telegram chat commands
i created app that communicate with telegram chat commands like /start
if users send messages equals "/start" then app send a reply
here is my code
private void respondToCommand() {

        botTokens = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.botToken);
        chatId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatId);
        String botTokenStr = botTokens.getText().toString();
        String chatIdStr = chatId.getText().toString();

        if (botTokenStr.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bot token is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {

            telegramApiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+botTokens.getText().toString()+"/getUpdates?limit=1&offset=-1";

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, telegramApiUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONArray resultArr = response.getJSONArray("result");
                        if (resultArr.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try to send command in group chat.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < resultArr.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = resultArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("message");
                                String msgText = c.getString("text");

                                String firstname = c.getString("chat");
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                Data data = gson.fromJson(firstname, Data.class);
                                if(data.id.equals(chatIdStr))
                                {
                                    if(msgText.equals("/start")){
                                        //sending reply
                                        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(botTokenStr, chatIdStr, "Started"+ UUID.randomUUID());
                                        resultToken.setText("reply to command : "+msgText);
                                    }else{
                                        resultToken.setText("it's a message : "+msgText);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    resultToken.setText("not chat");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);

        }

    }

the error i get that application when get command it send a reply continuously until user send other message not contains command
error showed in telegram group chat
i want to reply to command once every user send command to group.
any help.
i searched all question and tried most github java telegrambotapi libs and i found nothing.
i solved it by using this app opensource https://github.com/telegram-sms/telegram-sms

I would start with commenting this result to the console - JSONArray resultArr = response.getJSONArray("result");

for loops can be tricky - break; on a new line is a good way to stop them when you have done what you need to

most likely your issue is in this line - are you able to send the method code?
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(botTokenStr, chatIdStr, "Started" + UUID.randomUUID());

my app process : read messages -> ok, check if command -> ok, reply to command -> ok but when app read messages again old message still exist my reply from it's not showed in results so my app when read command it will send command reply without stop as i showed in picture in the question until any one in chat send other message/s if there other way for sending and receive group chat updates type answer with full details, thanks for your concern.

Is there a value to check who sent the message and not reply if it wasn't the user that sent the message?

in telegram api there is a value message and type of user {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":752696058,
"message":{"message_id":654,"from":{"id":7118772186,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Abdulrahman","last_name":"Abdulwahab","username":"CoderAbdulrahman","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":-1002007254688,"title":"testSms","type":"supergroup"},"date":1715188060,"text":"."}}]}
